# Oracle sql - How do I get the most updated value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to pull in the most recently updated lines. I tried using the MAX function in the select statement but am just getting the same results as I do when just doing a select *:

```
select max(last_update_date),vendor_id, last_update_date, last_updated_by , VENDOR_SITE_CODE
from POZ_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL_M
group by vendor_id, last_update_date, last_updated_by, VENDOR_SITE_CODE
```

This is the table:
[image]

This is the result I want:

[image]

What condition or function do I have to use to get the results I want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` to achieve your expected result.

```
select 
    vendor, 
    vendor_site
    last_update_date, 
    last_updated_by
from    
(
    select 
        vendor, 
        vendor_site
        last_update_date, 
        last_updated_by, 
        row_number() over (partition by vendor, vendor_site order by last_update_date desc) as rnk
    from POZ_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL_M
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.lastupdateddate = (select max(t2.lastupdateddate)
                           from t t2
                           where t2.vendor = t.vendor and t2.vendorsite = t.vendorsite
                          );
```

Another method uses aggregation and `keep`:

```
select vendor, vendorsite, max(lastupdateddate),
       max(lastupdatedby) keep (dense_rank first order by lastupdateddate desc) as lastupdatedby
from t
group by vendor, vendorsite;
```

The `keep` expression is Oracle's (rather verbose) way of saying "first".

Of course, there is also the `row_number()` approach as well.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the first option and it worked perfectly.